# Way to create a Group box constructor Visual Studio? (Rookie question)

Tags: visual-studio, constructor, groupbox

I created a group box with everything I want in place (see image) - Now is there a way(I.E. - menu option) to create a constructor for this? Looking for something similar to this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.groupbox.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2). The only difference is that I pre made my group box so that I could visualize it, now I need a constructor for it so that I can create it into an array. I hope this makes sense to you guys - I am new to Visual Studios(Dumbed down answers are appreciated). Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You should have started with a new **UserControl**.  Then you could add a GroupBox and set its Dock property to Fill.  Add all the controls and there you go...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks, I managed to figure it out - it is not as straightforward as I would like- but I got it done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Designer file for your form (it's listed in the Solution Explorer window), you will see the code-generated for your groupbox, and any other controls on the form.  It will look something like this:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // groupBox1
    // 
    this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 28);
    this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
    this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
    this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
    this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped very much - It took some tweaking but I managed to figure it out!